# Jquery Chain Async Methods to Use Them Sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

How to run async codes as sync in jquery / or javascript ?

I'm using EC5 and Jquery 1.8

I have 3 dropdownlists;
- City
- County
- Districts

I assigned a jquery event to first selection which named id: "CityId". When user select a city, I need to set CountyId (2.dropdown) value to zero. And "showHideDistrictSelection" method looks for selected CityId and selected Districts to decide show districts or not.

**The problem is, function "showHideDistrictSelection" works very fast, before setting CountyId value to 0**. Here is code;

```
    $("#CityId").change(function () {

        $("#CountyId").val("0");
        showHideDistrictSelection("#DistrictArea");

    });
```

So I changed event function like this;

```
        $("#CityId").change(function () {
            $("#CountyId").val("0");

            setTimeout(function() {
                showHideDistrictSelection("DistrictArea");
            }, 200);
        });
```

Now it's working, **but I'm sure this is not best practice.** I think I have an async problem here. So what do I need? deferred objects done(), when(), promise() functions etc? or other events? I'm using jquery but if you want to provide some codes, vanilla js will be ok too.

i will be gladful for any comments ( change your question's title, change your question, do this, make that etc. )

**Update**, I've added the show/hide districts function;

```
function showHideDistrictSelection() {
    var selectedCityText = $('#CityId :selected').text().toLowerCase();
    var selectedCountyId = $("#CountyId :selected").val();
    var $districtDropDownList = $("#DistrictId");

    if (selectedCityText.endsWith("w york") && selectedCountyId > 0) {
        $("#DistrictArea").show();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: addressUrls.GetDistricts,
            data: { countyId: selectedCountyId },
            success: function (data) {
                $districtDropDownList.html("");
                $("#DistrictId").append("<option value='0' selected='selected'>Select (*)</option>");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $districtDropDownList.append("<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].name + "</option>");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#DistrictArea").hide();
        $('#DistrictId').val("0");
    }
}
```

So function showHideDistrictSelection works very fast, before I set the CountyId value to 0 on change event...; I mean, When I get the selectedCountyId by $("#CountyId :selected").val(); I've still CountyId bigger then 0. Because $("#CountyId").val("0"); not completed the job.

*Sorry I'm little bit tried to define the problem clearly.*

Comment: `The problem is, function "showHideDistrictSelection" works very fast, before setting CountyId value to 0` That's not possible, as `val()` is a synchronous method. Could you please show the logic of `showHideDistrictSelection()`

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is that you need to solve

Comment: `How to run async codes as sync in jquery / or javascript ?` set the `$ajax` async property to false: `async:false`

Comment: @JosanIracheta absolutely not!... that is a terrible practice and is deprecated by the browser vendors

Comment: You cannot run async methods synchronously. You can make them run sequentially, but sync is impossible.

Comment: @charlietfl hmm you're right I just checked the jquery docs. I didn't know that. thank you :)

Comment: Never seen a problem setting a value and then it not completed when you try to retrieve the value immediately but if using setTimeout helps , go for it. Shouldn't need that long ... even no duration would probably work

Comment: Try using `$("#CountyId").val()` instead of `$("#CountyId :selected").val()`

Comment: You can try using a `MutationObserver` and wait for the `#CountyId` `value` to change and then run the function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver